# Attempting to define a C data structure in SWIG, and access it in Tcl

Tags: struct, tcl, swig

According to the SWIG documentation, I should be able to wrap a C data structure definition like so:

```
struct Vector {
    double x,y,z;
};
```

...and then create a new instance of it in Tcl like this:

```
% Vector v
```

...but when I try to do this, Tcl returns an error message "invalid command name 'Vector' ".

Clearly I am missing something.  Can anyone clue me in?  I am using SWIG 3.0.0 and Tcl 8.6...

Comment: Just to confirm… you do have the package generated by SWIG `load`ed into Tcl at the point when you try that?

Comment: Yes; the load itself seems to work OK.  If I do "info commands" in the Tcl shell window after loading my custom DLL, I can see the commands I created.

Comment: If `info commands` lists it, you can call it. (You might not be able to call it correctly, but that's something else.) Does `info commands *ector*` find anything relevant?

Comment: I understand that if 'info' lists it I can call it, and it DOES list the commands I created.  However, I'm led to believe (from the SWIG documentation) that, by virtue of the fact that I've defined a data structure, that there are some functions automagically created by SWIG to create, access, and destroy such structures from the target language (Tcl, in my case).

Answer (score 1):

After some more study and experimentation, I figured out my problem.

In the SWIG-3.0 documentation, section 5.5.8, this statement is made:

> SWIG doesn't care if the declaration of a structure in a .i file
>   exactly matches that used in the underlying C code (except in the case
>   of nested structures). For this reason, there are no problems omitting
>   problematic members or simply omitting the structure definition
>   altogether. If you are happy passing pointers around, this can be done
>   without ever giving SWIG a structure definition.

I do not have a nested structure, so I apparently took the statement "this can be done without ever giving SWIG a structure definition" a bit too literaly; I did not include a structure definition in my .i file (other than its declaration in the '.h' file for my C source, specified in the "% incude %{ ... %} section of the .i file).

When I included my structure typemap statement in my .i file, all the documented functions were created by SWIG and work as expected from Tcl.